# How to add logo in 2fa email template in magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

**I want to add shop logo(dynamic) in 2Fa (Magento_TwoFactorAuth) email templates.**

```
<img src="{{view url='Magento_TwoFactorAuth/images/logo_email.png'}}"  />
```

i can add logo  but this is static logo i need dynamic.

Comment: logo always needs to be replaced for email templates.

Comment: You could always add your own template vars by overriding it notifier. \Magento\TwoFactorAuth\Model\EmailUserNotifier::sendConfigRequired